# Angular CLI Services stored String variable always return to default value

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm new to angular CLI.  this happened when I tried to pass a string value to services and later tried to retrieve it in another component

**select.ts**

```
public gotofriends(fname:string, fpic:string){    
    const service = new FbdetailsService();
    service.selectedfrienddetails(fname, fpic);
    this.router.navigate(['calculate']);
}
```

**select.html**

```
<button (click)="gotofriends(user.name,user.picture.data.url)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mx-1">Select &nbsp;</button>
```

**fbdetails service**

```
export class FbdetailsService {
    fbname;
    fbpic;
    public selectedfrienddetails(name: string, profilephoto: string) {
        this.fbname = name;
        this.fbpic = profilephoto;
        console.log("selected friend details", this.fbname, this.fbpic)
    }


    public returnfrienddetails() {
        console.log(this.fbname, this.fbpic)
    }
}
```

**calculate componet.ts**

```
public printname(){
    const service = new FbdetailsService();
    service.returnfrienddetails()
}
```

**calculate HTML**

```
<button (click)="printname()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mx-1">Calculate</button>
```

when I call **selectedfrienddetails()** in **selectcomponet.ts** it succefully printing string to console but when I tried to call **returnfrienddetails()** in **calculatecomponent.ts**  it doesn't print any value .

then I tried adding two buttons to **selectcomponent.ts**
first one pass **selectedfrienddetails()** and successfully print variable then   second one call **returnfrienddetails()**  but as in first case  **returnfrienddetails()** didn't print anything.

Comment: Work through the detailed tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, services are singletons. That means there is only one instance of them.

What you, is creating a second :

```
const service = new FbdetailsService();
```

You should not. Instead, you should inject your service into your components. For that, decorate your service as injectable, and inject it into your component constructors.